Impact of Excluding Artifacts from GitLab Backups
I'm seeking advice on managing GitLab backups for our company's codebase and have some specific concerns regarding the exclusion of artifacts. Here are the details of our current environment:

GitLab Version: 14.4.2

Disk Size: 6T

GitLab Artifacts: 3.6T

PostgreSQL Database Size: 44GB


We're considering using the gitlab-backup create command to exclude artifacts from our backups due to their substantial size. I'm keen to understand the implications of making this decision, particularly regarding:
The impact on our ability to restore from these backups.
Best practices for mitigating potential risks associated with excluding artifacts from backups.
Any insights, experiences, or advice you could share would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your assistance!
